# Get data from each select in the loop Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of products to fill (Product fields: {type:"",name:""}).
There is a variable that takes the number of products to enter. Then, for each product, a separate div is rendered with one select and one input text.
I need to get data from each such block and put them in an array.

```
      <div v-for="n in parseInt(countProd)" :key="n">
        <div>
          <select>
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
            <option>option3</option>
          </select>
          <input placeholder="Product name">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this make sense.

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data() {
        return {
          title: "Vue 2 app",
          countProd:0,
          products:[]
        };
      },
      watch:{
        countProd(newVal,old){
          console.log(old,newVal)
          this.products=Array.from({length:newVal},(v,i)=>{
            return { type:'1', name:''}
          })
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
No. of Products:
<input v-model="countProd" />
<div v-for="(p,n) in products" :key="n">
        <div>
          <select v-model="products[n].type">
            <option value="1">option1</option>
            <option value="2">option2</option>
            <option value="3">option3</option>
          </select>
          <input placeholder="Product name" v-model="products[n].name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p v-if="products.length>0">{{products}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how concat values of 2 selects, like : 
<select v-model="products[n].type">
            <option value="1">option1</option>
            <option value="2">option2</option>
            <option value="3">option3</option>
          </select>

<select v-model="products[n].type2">
            <option value="4">option4</option>
            <option value="5">option5</option>
            <option value="6">option6</option>
          </select>
and final type like : "option1" + "option4"

Comment: currently the final shape is `[{type:'1',name:'one'},{...},{...}]` how do you want the shape?

Comment: the final form is the same [{type:'1',name:'one'},{...},{...}], but the type is assembled from two selects

Comment: There could be n no. of items. how and which 2 selects you want to concat?

Comment: By concatenation, I meant combining the values ​​of the first and second select. For example, with 1 select, I chose option1, and from the second select, option4. Then type = "option1" + "option4". 
As a result, you should get:
 [{type: 'option1 + option4', name: 'name'}, {...}, {...}]

Comment: why do you want like that. rather have 2 select for each product and 2nd select can be optional

Comment: the product type itself consists of two words, so you need 2 selections to accurately determine the type